# How are ties in a US Congressional election dealt with?

Tags: united-states, us-constitution, colorado

Suppose candidates Alice and Bob are running for US House of Representatives in a Colorado district, and are the only people to do so in that district. The final vote tally (after whatever challenges Alice and Bob decide to throw) comes out to a tie. How would the tie be broken?

Answer (score 5):

Election procedures are generally a matter of state law, so the process will be different from one state to the next. In Colorado, the law in question is [Colo. Rev. Stat. § 1-11-101](https://codes.findlaw.com/co/title-1-elections/co-rev-st-sect-1-11-101/):

> If at any general or congressional vacancy election ... any two or more persons tie for the highest number of votes ... for representative in congress ... *the secretary of state shall proceed to determine by lot which of the candidates shall be declared elected*.

The question then becomes how the secretary of state will "determine by lot" who is the winner. As far as I can tell, this process is not established by statute, nor has the secretary of state promulgated any administrative regulations establishing a system for drawing lots. In other states, it typically comes down to something quite random: [flipping coins](http://archive.kucb.org/news/article/breaking-news-bryce-edgmon-wins-coin-toss/), [drawing names from a hat](https://www.orlandosentinel.com/news/lake/os-mount-dora-winner-to-be-picked-20141202-story.html), [dealing poker](https://www.nytimes.com/1998/03/08/us/national-news-briefs-a-coin-then-cards-and-finally-a-mayor.html), etc; I assume the secretary of state could choose any of these.

The answer could be different for other races, though. Both chambers of the General Assembly would vote on a joint ballot to decide a tie in a race for governor, secretary of state, treasurer, or attorney general.

This also assumes that Bob and Alice are facing off in the general election, not the primary. In a primary, tying candidates get to choose their own tiebreaker. If they can't agree on one, the secretary of state chooses by lot.

Comment: Kudos for completeness.